# CSS Hover Divider

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

This project I am working on is in Pure HTML & CSS.

I have a menu bar with CSS hover attributes, and what I am trying to accomplish is the green horizontal hover line when a menu drop down is hovered over as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZV9t.jpg).

Here is where I am stuck at - https://jsfiddle.net/Kitana16/t0mx1h8f/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <a href="#home">CONTACT</a>
  <a href="#home">BLOG</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">PRODUCTS</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a>
      <a href="#">FEATURED</a>
      <a href="#">TOP RATED</a>
      <a href="#">HIS</a>
      <a href="#">HERS</a>
      <a href="#">KIDS</a>
      <a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a>
      <a href="#">SPRING CATALOG</a>
      <a href="#">THE ESSENTIALS</a>
      <a href="#">SALE</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">LOCATIONS</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
       <a href="#">AUSTIN, TX</a>
      <a href="#">ATLANTA, GA</a>
      <a href="#">SEATTLE, WA</a>
      <a href="#">PORTLAND, OR</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">ABOUT</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">OUR STORY</a>
      <a href="#">OUR COMMITMENT TO YOU</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<div style='position:absolute;z-index:-1;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%'>
  <img src='http://www.getuwired.com/devtest/Death_to_stock_photography_Vibrant.jpg' style='width:100%;height:100%' alt='[]' />
</div>


</body>
```

CSS

```
 .container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: -8px;
    height: 60px;
}

.container a {
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #36363F;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 70px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: calibri;
}

.container b {
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #36363F;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 70px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: calibri;
}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #36363F;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: calibri;
}

.container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #33CB98;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #33CB98;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #019966;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change a parent's style on his child's event. The best way to accomplish your result in my opinion, is adding this:

```
.container:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 0 #33CB98;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0mx1h8f/1/)

How's that?

Comment: OMG!  Thank You SOOOO Much!  Is there anyway i can get rid of that small gap between the menu item and the divider line?

Comment: You have the gap because of the `.container`'s `height` property. Change it to 50px or something like in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0mx1h8f/2/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Kitana16/t0mx1h8f/5/ - How can I extend the horizontal hover under the heading on the left?

Comment: Put the `title` div inside the `container` div, and remove `background-color: white;` from `.title`. Check out this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0mx1h8f/7/), I also played with the CSS a bit to make things look better.

Comment: Thank You For Your Help Itay !!!!! After I figure out how to zoom in on the background like the example I think i will be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

In the .container
change the value of  height:50px;
:)

Comment: This is the answer to the second question :)

Comment: Are you aware of how I can get the white space between the top of the page and my hover menu items as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZV9t.jpg

Comment: .container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin: 10px -8px;
    height: 50px;
}

Comment: <div style='position:absolute;z-index:-1;left:0;top:10;width:100%;height:100%'>

Comment: replace both of them in your css and should work. let me know

Comment: it did not work for me, this is what i got - https://jsfiddle.net/Kitana16/t0mx1h8f/15/

Comment: Do some research first, honey. You've added html code into your css file...

Comment: replace in your css file, this: .container { overflow: hidden; background-color: white; font-family: Arial; margin: -8px; height: 50px; } 

with this 
{ overflow: hidden; background-color: white; font-family: Arial; margin: 10px -8px; height: 50px; } 

and replace <div style='position:absolute;z-index:-1;left:0;top:0;width:100%‌​;height:100%'> 

in your html code with this: <div style='position:absolute;z-index:-1;left:0;top:10;width:100%‌​;height:100%'>